# Facebook Graph Api - How can i get historical POST likes?

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api, graphql, facebook-insights

I've been attempting to figure this out for a while, but how can i get historical data for post insights? For example, i need to get a "snapshot" of the insights for every day throughout the last five years.  Its easy to get the latest stats, just use period = lifetime, but i need to the lifetime stats on a day three years ago. Is this even possible using only the graph api?

Thanks!

Comment: While I can appreciate what you're asking, the lack of code may attract downvotes. For most API's, to do what you're looking to do would require you to take your own snapshots on a periodic basis, though I'll defer to someone who actually knows the Facebook Graph API.

Comment: Yep, we are currently taking a snapshot every day of all our posts. We were just hoping it was possible to "look back in time" because we only recently started doing that.

Answer (score 0):

only 90 days of insights can be viewed at one time when using since and until parameters in the Graph API. Just use the daily metrics and the since and until parameters in calls. Please refer to  [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/insights)